# Rails - Display associated data in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here are my models:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users

# Data name:string

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :account
```

So when I try to call for the name of the Account associated to User in view index.html.erb:

```
<%= user.account.name %>
```

I get error

```
NoMethodError in Users#index
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Does it have to do with my controller?

```
def index
@users = User.all
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, at least one of your `User` records doesn't have its `Account` associated, so `user.account` returns `nil`. Answering directly to your question: No it has nothing to do with your controller (controller code is correct).

If you let users without accounts exist, you can avoid error with [`Object#try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) method:

```
<%= user.account.try(:name) %>
```

This method returns actual account name if it's present. Otherwise (i.e. if `user.account` returns `nil`) it returns `nil`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask another question, if I must have many users without Account is there a way to display this code without error?

Comment: @user3794309 I edited to answer your second question.